# Apache Mahout and REST Java Web Application Integration

Tags: rest, maven, mahout, jersey-2.0

I have a problem with link those two things - Apache Mahout and Java Web Application Integration.

I use standard Java Web Application Maven project and Jersey 2.4 to build my webservice. My application server is Apache Tomcat 7.

When I run this project without Mahout and try:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://myhost:8089/ensembleRestApi/recommeng/algorithm/articleCore/cf?limit=5'
```

I got response and also can go through source code (with debugger)

But when I add Mahot dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And try to do the same curl command, I got this AbstractMethodError yet before breakpoint in webservice method is invocated in my source code:

Do you know where is the problem please?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-serlvet] in context with path     [/ensembleRestApi] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:     javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I would assume you don't have added a real implementation (AbstractMethodError) ?

Comment: How do you mean this? AbstractMethodError is often caused by incompatible Jersey version (see google - http://tinyurl.com/lh8s9pm)... but this is not my problem. I had implemented my User based collaborative filtering (here http://pastebin.com/k2WjsQhV) and it was working as a standalone Java Application. But when I added it into this web application.. there occured error described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so if somebody will fight with the same thing, remember that this exception is because of:

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.
>   by [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html)

This means that you have some conflicts in libraries (which are in dependencies)

So I tried to downgrade my mahout-core library version and with version 0.7 everything works fine.

Comment: Have you found a solution to use the newest mahout version?

Comment: No, I have not used it since.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem, and it's because of a conflict in Jersey versions.  For my endpoints, I'm using Jersey 2.14.  But Mahout 0.9 depends on hadoop-core 1.2.1, which has several Jersey 1.8 dependencies.  The AbstractMethodError is caused because your endpoint is using a Jersey 1.8 class which does not have this method defined.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all the com.sun.jersey dependencies from your pom.xml...Here I'm using gradle:

```
compile ('org.apache.mahout:mahout-integration:0.11.1'){
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey'
}
```

In eclipse you can go to your 'Maven Dependencies' folder in your project -> right click-> 'Maven' ->'Exclude Maven Artifact...' for all the 'jersey1.xxx' dependencies and the exclusions will be added in your pom.xml file